# How can I ensure Ruby is using the Rack gem that's vendored in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

My Rails 2.3.x application is failing, because it's using the wrong version of Rack ([one with a bug](https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/291)).  There are two versions of Rack on my system, a vendored one (the right version) and a system one, installed via `apt-get`.

Why is it using the wrong version? This is particularly puzzling me because the vendored version is being correctly used earlier in the call stack.  And how I can make it use the right version?

Here's an excerpt from the stack trace I'm getting when the application fails:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/utils.rb:202:in `set_cookie_header!'
/home/alaveteli/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/response.rb:57:in `set_cookie'
/home/alaveteli/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/response.rb:181:in `set_cookie'
```

Note that line 2 is using the vendored Rack, but line 1 is using the system Rack.  (Line 57 of `response.rb` calls a module from Rack, thus: `Utils.set_cookie_header!(header, key, value)`.)

My `$LOAD_PATH` is as I believe it should be, with the vendored gems coming before the system ones.

Yes, I am planning to migrate to using Bundler soonish.

Comment: Perhaps try uninstalling the one you installed via apt-get?

Comment: That's not an option on this system -- and anyway, I want to understand why my vendored version isn't working so I can ensure my software will work anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) and ruby-build. It's a sane ruby version management system (unlike rvm which is insane). You get a ruby version per folder and all it's gems. When I have alaveteli issues, I usually ask them on the dev mailing list. I run the Romanian alaveteli.